# Regular Expression to Capture First Two Lines That Don't Include String

Tags: regex

I am struggling to find a method to extract the first two lines of an address using a regular expression, where it doesn't include the word "Account".

If we take this address:

> Company Name 
>  Some Road 
>  Some Town

I can use the regular expression `(?:.*\s*){2}` to return

> Company Name Some Road

Which is great.

However, if there is an extra line at the top, making the address become:

> **Accounts Payable** 
>  Company Name 
>  Some Road 
>  Some Town

Then it no longer picks up those two lines that I want.

I have tried the method here: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) without success, and have also tried combinations of using things like `(?!Account.*)(?:.*\s*){3}`, but am having little success.

The Microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference has masses of characters etc to use, but I haven't managed to get a combination working yet.

The closest I've got was using `[^Account.*](?:.*\s*){3}` which returns

> s Payable 
>    Company Name 
>    Some Road

I just can't get it to remove the rest of that line! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try `^(?!Accounts)(?:.*\n?){2}` with `^` in multiline mode. If it is not a text editor, add `(?m)` to the start of the regex. See https://regex101.com/r/1Ci5yD/1

Comment: Your answer with adding (?m) to the start has accomplished what I needed! This is the missing part of the puzzle! Place this as an answer, and I'll mark it as the accepted one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `^` with multiline mode on:

```
(?m)^(?!Accounts)(?:.*\n?){2}
```

Or (a bit more efficient and following best practices):

```
(?m)^(?!Accounts).*(?:\n.*)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ci5yD/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ci5yD/2).

When `(?m)` is added to the pattern, `^` matches start of a *line*, and the whole pattern matches

- `^` - start of  a line
- `(?!Accounts)` - with no `Accounts` as the first word
- `(?:.*\n?){2}` - two occurrences of any 0+ chars other than line break chars followed with an optional newline
- `.*(?:\n.*)?` - matches a line and an optional subsequent line.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the explanation and link.